# HDMI Audio not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi

I am trying to connect a home theater system to my TV and computer.

at this moment everything works, I have a Onkyo HT S3800 5.1 Home Theater System connected with an UHD TV Grundig 49 GUB 8960 on standard DVBT-2 terrestrial TV the sound goes to AV via HDMI ARC.

the computer is connected via HDMI to AV reciever.

At this moment the computer specs are:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 3400g (OC @ 4.1 GHz stable); GPU: (OC @ 1.7 GHz);; VRAM: 2 GB (stable)
MB: MSI B450 Tomahawk
RAM: Corsair RGB PRO 16 GB (XMP enabled, with some latency tweaking (stable))
SSD: Samsung 970 PRO 512 GB
monitor: Acer SA220QAb (connected to MB DVI connector via HDMI 1.4 cable and HDMI-DVI adapter)
the Onkyo AV reciever is connected to MB HDMI connector via HDMI 1.4 cable
the Grunding TV is connected to Onkyo AV reciever via HDMI 1.4 cable with ARC enabled

Now this is where strange things happen...+
I decided to add a discrete GPU to my system, I chosen Gigabyte Aorus RX 560 (https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-RX560OC-4GD-rev-20#kf this one not the one with two fans- I found it for a great deal and I couldn't afford a better one) Anyway this is the only change I make.
so with all previous mentioned specs just add that GPU running on stock.
all drivers are up to date.

as soon as I connect everything, my TV to HDMI connector and monitor to DVI connector using the adapter, just like before, I can't get sound on my TV or Onkyo AV reciever, I tried connecting just the TV bypassing the Home theater system, but still, there is no device to output sound to apart from my speaker connected to my computer.
Video is working though
I tried connecting to different HDMI In ports on both my TV and AV reciever, but my computer just doesnt see speakers connected to HDMI on my GPU, when I go to troubleshoot, it does see HDMI Audio on my GPU but it says that there are no speakers connected to that port.
Than I tried updating drivers - not working
Uninstall drivers completelly, leaving just basic graphics driver from Microsoft - not working (in fact I can't even get video to my TV if I do that)
Reinstall again performing a Factory Reset, used older WHQL version from AMD - not working
Now I disconnected my monitor and leave just the TV pluged in - not working
I thought there is a conflict between my iGPU and new descrete GPU, so I disabled iGPU in BIOS and allocate 64 MB (minimum) of RAM to the iGPU)
Tried everything again - not working
Reenabled iGPU again set allocated memory size back to 2 GB
disconnected my monitor again and leave just the TV pluged in - not working
connected the monitor back to MB DVI port - video working but no audio again
connected TV back to MB HDMI port - now something new happens - all I get on my TV is a completelly green screen, nothing else just a dark green screen.
took the Graphics card out return everything back as it was and brought the card to service center to test for audio, since apart from that TV I cant test it elsewhere.
They did plug it to the TV - not sure if it was exactlly the same - i think not, or that they had exactlly the same PC but as they say it did have the iGPU, again not sure which one because they didn't say, what they did say is that Audio is working fine.
but if everything is fine why can't I get audio...

I think maybe the cables, they are all 1.4 and the TV is 4k HDR so the cables might be causing this...
Anyway I ordered 3 pcs 3m long HDMI 2.0 cables with 1 pcs HDMI repeater because the computer is in another room and I need at least 6 m cable lenght and 2.0 is strugling on 5 m long, the third cable will go to my reciever from the TV for ARC feature.

My question is: will this help, I mean I think the cables are to blame but am I correct? if not I still need 2.0 cables to make HDR working.
And why else can't I get sound out of my GPU?

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

EDIT: New cables have arrived, this is how I connected them.

So I used 3 cables 3m long each and a single HDMI 4k repeater.

I connected first cable to my PC and input port on the repeater, and secound cable to output port on repeater to TV, third cable goes from TV ARC to AVR.

At some point I actually got audio to work from my GPU (it did recognise the TV) but I had some resolution issues (The TV would have a scalled up blurry image, like my GPU is processing at 1080, and than my TV is upscaling that, while my monitor is getting 1080p, or vice versa, my GPU would be processing at 4k and than I would get a quarter of image on my main 1080p monitor - solved that by enabling VSR in Radeon settings, but than I lost audio, now if I disable it I still don't have audio)

Now I repeat all the things I done before plus, I installed and reinstalled speciffically the AMD High Definition Audio driver, and I still can't get sound to work, if I connect the cables to my MB/iGPU i get sound but no HDR since it's a 1.4 port, however the sound is stereo only can't switch to 5.1 because it is grayed out for some reason in sound settings, I guess my TV won't forward more than two channels of Audio through ARC, even though I can't see why, when I go to my TV settings I can activate surround sound, and there is a setting can't remember what it's called but options are "PCM" or "Passthrough" - whichever I choose won't do anything, under HDMI section, there is also something called HDMI EDID - options are: "default", "1.4", "2.0" - I set this to 2.0 - I guess this tells the TV what sort of signal te expect.
Also now when I connect the cable to my GPU, I can get HDR and all that but no sound -  I tried installing the driver from CD that came with the GPU to no avail, I also tried installing drivers from Windows Update, but nothing.

I really don't want to throw a good GPU away because of some stupid driver issue, and I can't afford new one, is there something I didn't try but could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

DVI connectors must use DVI protocol and DVI protocol cannot carry audio. DVI protocol can be received by HDMI devices, and HDMI devices are allowed to send DVI protocol.

Comment: I know, I am trying to get Audio on my HDMI connected TV which is connected to HDMI port on my MB/GPU dirrectlly, however my main monitor which doesn't have speakers anyway is connected to DVI because the monitor has only VGA and HDMI input, and since I don't have another HDMI or VGA port on my MB/GPU, I had to use DVI to HDMI adapter. The reason why I mentioned the monitor that I normally use and is constantlly connected is because I am not sure if the monitor might cause any conflicts since it's a 1080p and my TV is 4k.

Answer (score 0):

On your computer you have to select the playback device. Click on Speaker  icon on the right bottom of the desktop and click on the arrow. Then select the **`HDMI`** as the playback device.

Comment: I tried that, as mentioned above " there is no device to output sound to apart from my speaker connected to my computer" and here: "my computer just doesnt see speakers connected to HDMI on my GPU, when I go to troubleshoot, it does see HDMI Audio on my GPU but it says that there are no speakers connected to that port."

Comment: Edit: so I get only Realtek speaker, which is my MB sound controller, to which my main computer speakers are connected to, and Steam streaming speakers, which Don't give sound anywhere, I think those are some sort of virtual speakers, I don't know. when I go to troubleshoot, than it asks me which device I want to troubleshoot, and appart from the two I mentioned I get two AMD High definition Audio Device HDMI - those are HDMI, but when I click that, it would say that no speaker is connected to that port.